# Translation help:: How to translate 我们经常会怎么说 into English?

Tags: translation

> 假如我们现在碰到有个人，觉得他实在太不争气，实在太让我们失望，我们对他又爱、又恨、又急，那么`我们经常会怎么说`？

We often do what/as we say?

This is from an ancient text so I'm not sure if the style of language back then is different from today's.

http://www.jxjjxx.com/web/jxjjxx_detail.php?dlmmc=%BD%CC%B9%A4%D6%AE%BC%D2&lmmc=%C8%D5%D0%C2%BD%B2%CC%B3&zlmmc=%C8%D5%D0%C2%BD%B2%CC%B3&wzid=620&lbid=322

Comment: The text given by the link is not an ancient Chinese text. It's a modern interpretation of a paragraph of ancient text.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

假如我们现在碰到有个人，觉得他实在太不争气，实在太让我们失望，我们对他又爱、又恨、又急、
**那么我们经常会怎么说**？

I think here it means: "so then is that how we usually put it?", "so is that how it is usually said?"

Comment: Just quote the complete context :) "假如我们现在碰到有个人，觉得他实在太不争气，实在太让我们失望，我们对他又爱、又恨、又急， **那么我们经常会怎么说？你啊，简直是朽木不可雕也。** " => ... so how do we usually express it? (We usually say:) "You are really uneducable."

Answer (score 1):

it means "*then* **what we usually say** *to him*?", it's usually followed by an answer.

Answer (score 0):

我们会怎么说=How will we say (about) / criticize it?

我们会说什么=What will we say?

And, here 经常=normally / usually **rather than** often